# How to replace the input data from the random integer generator in Simulink OFDM into a fixed defined input data

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink model for an OFDM simulation. I was able to build the model from tutorial in the internet. The model looks something like this:

[OFDM Simulink Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFWBX.jpg)

Now, what I want to do is to generate an input integer stream with fixed and defined values (specifically this integer sequence: [84   104   105   115    32   105   115    32    97    32   116   101   115   116    46]), instead of using the Random Integer Generator (the first block in the model).

What block should I use? I tried using the Repeating Sequence Stair block but it does not provide a frame-based output similar to the Random Integer Generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the [Buffer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/buffer.html) block to convert the output of your Repeating Sequence to an appropriately sized frame.

You could also consider just using a Constant block, with the output being set to be a 1D vector, instead of the Repeating Sequence block.  (You'd still need the Buffer block.)

Or, you could define the sequence as a variable in the MATLAB Workspace and use the [Signal From Workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/signalfromworkspace.html) block (note, this is the one in the DSP Toolbox, not the From Workspace block in the basic Simulink Sources library), which can be set to output a frame.